How to get string with disctinct (unique) characters from existing string in bash script?
For example, I have string:
explicit_borders="\"\"''()"

How to calculate based on this string the string with the following result:
distinct_border_chars="\"'()"  # contains only unique set of chars

To solve this should I loop over each char in the string and add the char only if the result string does not contain it? Or perhaps is there some simpler bash-specific solution?

Update
I would prefer solutions based on bash built-ins without additional subshell creation (that are using pipes | and command substitution with $()) since they will work better from stand point of performance.
And better without here-strings (<<< ...) since they are creating temporary files which impacts performance.
But actually any solutions can also be considered (especially simple and concise) to have more choice.

Here's the same problem (with solutions) for each line of input: How can I find unique characters per line of input? That said, how about fold -w1 <<< "$explicit_borders" | sort -u | paste -sd ''?

@pmf Thanks. This approach as I understand uses not bash built in functions and will create bunch of subshells (sub processes) for each pipe. It is not good from stand point of performance. In the first place I want to consider solution without creating additional subshells.

distinct_border_chars=$( sed -r 's/(.)\1/\1/g' <<< "$explicit_borders" )

@Wiimm this seems to be hard code ) Does not work for: explicit_borders="'(\"\"''()"; res=$( sed -r 's/(.)\1/\1/g' <<< "$explicit_borders" ); echo $res

@Wiimm But interesting solution for this particular example. Thanks.

@Wiimm what \1 group mean in regex part of sed? Or this is not group?

@Wiimm Ah, got it. It seems that regex groups also can be used in find part of sed, not only in replacement part. Did not know that.

@Wiimm I think this solution is worth to be amount other answers. Sometimes things can be done more simper like with this approach.

\1 is a back reference to the first (...) part. So (.)\1 means: any character that is followed by the same character.

@AntonSamokat I used your example for my sed solution. Here is another solution that orders the chars and remove duplicates: distinct_border_chars=$( grep -o . <<< "$explicit_borders" | sort -u | tr -d '\n' )

Yes it can be done in pure bash, all we need is an associative array to behave as a hash-map and key each character as it occurs in the input string. If the char has appeared once, append it to the final result
#!/usr/bin/env bash

explicit_borders="\"\"''()"
declare -A seen
result=""

for (( i=0; i<${#explicit_borders}; i++ )); do
    c="${explicit_borders:$i:1}"
    if ! [[ -n "${seen[$c]}" ]]; then
        seen[$c]=1
        result+="$c"
    fi
done

printf -v result '%q' "$result"
printf "%s\n" "${result}"

The %q format specifier at the end causes printf to output the corresponding argument in a format that can be reused as shell input.

You can define this function
unique_chars() {
  head=
  tail=$1
  while test "$tail"; do
    next=${tail#?}
    char=${tail%"$next"}
    case $head in
    *"$char"*) ;;
    *) head=$head$char
    esac
    tail=$next
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$head"
}

and use it like so
$ explicit_borders="\"\"''()"
$ unique_chars "$explicit_borders"
"'()


Thanks. I would add for others that to get result of this function in the script command substitution $() should be used like: unique_chars_result=$(unique_chars "$explicit_borders")

It's best to avoid variable names that are the same as command names (head and tail) so as to not unnecessarily obfuscate your code and introduce potential bugs. You should also declare the function-local variables as local so the function doesn't accidentally overwrite variables of the same name in  the calling code.

Using only builtins and no subshells (e.g. as command substitution, $(command "$input"), would create) or temp files (e.g. as a here string, command <<<"$input", would create in bash 5.0 and older and could still create in bash 5.1 and newer):
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkuniq() {
    local instring=$1
    local -n outvar=$2
    local charpos char strlgth
    local -A chars

    strlgth="${#instring}"
    for (( charpos=0; charpos < strlgth; charpos++ )); do
        char="${instring:charpos:1}"
        chars["$char"]=1
    done

    printf -v outvar '%s' "${!chars[@]}"
}

explicit_border_chars="\"\"''()"

mkuniq "$explicit_border_chars" distinct_border_chars

printf 'explicit_border_chars=%s\n' "$explicit_border_chars"
printf 'distinct_border_chars=%s\n' "$distinct_border_chars"


$ ./tst.sh
explicit_border_chars=""''()
distinct_border_chars=)('"


Original answer before OP added the restriction about only wanting bash builtins and no subprocesses to their question:
$ explicit_borders="\"\"''()"
$ distinct_border_chars=$(grep -o . <<<"$explicit_borders" | sort -u | tr -d '\n')
$ echo "$distinct_border_chars"
"'()

Caveat: using tr -d '\n' assumes you don't have any newlines in explicit_borders

Below combination of Inian's and Ed Morton's answers:
cat string-utils.sh

#!/bin/bash

mk_unique() {
    local in_string=${1:?}
    local -n _mku__out_result=${2:?}
    _mku__out_result=""
    local char_pos char str_lgth
    local -A seen

    str_lgth="${#in_string}"
    for (( char_pos=0; char_pos < str_lgth; char_pos++ )); do
        char="${in_string:char_pos:1}"
        if ! [[ -n "${seen[$char]}" ]]; then
            seen[$char]=1
            _mku__out_result+="$char"
        fi
    done
}

explicit_border_chars="\"\"''()"

mk_unique "$explicit_border_chars" distinct_border_chars

printf 'explicit_border_chars=%s\n' "$explicit_border_chars"
printf 'distinct_border_chars=%s\n' "$distinct_border_chars"

$ ./string-utils.sh
explicit_border_chars=""''()
distinct_border_chars="'()

